# hive count(distinct) only one reducer

Tags: distinct, hive, aggregation

it's troubling me for a long time.  I like to use hive aggregation with **multiple distinct** like below:

```
select count(case when pv=1 then 1 else null end), count(distinct case when pv=1 and uid>1 then uid else null end), count(distinct component), count(message) from log_table;
```

this will lead to only **1 reducer** which make job very very a long time. Since most work are in **reducer job**.

it's not suitable to use **subquery** like below as there are several distinct columns.

```
 select count(1) from (select v from tbl group by v) t.
```

Any good idea to **optimize** this problem.  Only have to split it into several query and then join?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

did you try something like this:

```
select
 sum(a.pv_cnt),
 count(a.uniq_uids),
 count(a.uniq_uids),
 sum(a.msg_cnt)
from
  (
   select
     case when pv=1 then 1 else 0 end  as pv_cnt,
     distinct ( case when pv=1 and uid>1 then uid ) as uniq_uids,
     component,
     count(message) msg_cnt;
   from
    log_table
  )a;
```